# How to verify the response key in chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a response body as

```
[{
  "_id": "56fc22f625311b661becefb5",
  “activities”: [...],
  "lastName": “patrick”,
  "firstName": "John”,
  "city": “Chennai”,
  "state": “TAMILNADU”
}, {
  "_id": "56fc22f625311b661becefb6",
  “activities”: [...],
  "lastName": “sparrow”,
  "firstName": "John",
  "city": “Chennai”,
  "state": “TAMILNADU”
}]
```

when I make an API call via supertest in Mocha, I have to validate whether the response body's key has firstName,lastName and state and the value of state as TAMILNADU in chai.

How to do it, I tried

```
res.body.should.have.property("lastName");
res.body.should.have.property("state");
```

but getting an error as

> Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to have a property 'firstName'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your body contains an array, not an object so you need to access the first element of your array like this (not tested)

```
res.body[0].should.have.property("lastName");
res.body[0].should.have.property("state");
```

Since your array can contain several elements, you should loop through your array

```
res.body.forEach((item) => {
    item.should.have.property("lastName");
    item.should.have.property("state");
})
```